# get the value of variable from another method

Tags: java

How do i print the value of variable which is defined inside another method?

This might be a dumb question but please help me out as i am just a beginner in programming

```
public class XVariable {
    int c = 10; //instance variable

void read() {
    int b = 5;
    //System.out.println(b);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    XVariable d = new XVariable();
    System.out.println(d.c);
    System.out.println("How to print value of b here? ");
    //d.read();
}
}
```

Comment: You can't print the value of ```b``` since it is only accessible in that ```read``` method. I suggest you read about Java variable scopes. Try this website so that you can understand -> http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/scope-and-lifetime-of-variables

Comment: Integer read() {
    return 5;
    //System.out.println(b);
}

Answer (score 3):

You can't. `b` is a *local variable*. It only exists while `read` is executing, and if `read` executes multiple times (e.g. in multiple threads, or via recursive calls) each execution of `read` has its own separate variable.

You might want to consider *returning* the value from the method, or potentially using a field instead - it depends on what your real-world use case is.

The [Java tutorial section on variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) has more information on the various kinds of variables.

Comment: Maybe it's about time for Java in Depth :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return value from your read() methods.

```
public class XVariable {
    int c = 10; //instance variable

int read() {
    int b = 5;
    return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    XVariable d = new XVariable();
    System.out.println(d.c);
    System.out.println(read());
    //d.read();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return `b` from the `read` method and print it

```
public class XVariable {
    int c = 10; //instance variable

    int read() {
        int b = 5;
       return b;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XVariable d = new XVariable();
        System.out.println(d.c);
        System.out.println(d.read());
    }
}
```